# Cause: processResources.sourceOutputDir must not be null

Tags: android, build

Getting below error while building the project

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':express'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  > java.lang.IllegalStateException: processResources.sourceOutputDir must not be null
  > KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'preKitkatDebug' not found.
```

Tried to clean build and rebuild but it is not working.